# Streaming Youtube video in android VideoView

Tags: android, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-api, android-videoview

I am working on an app which stream youtube videos.
Here is my code snippet :

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(PlayVideo.this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView_Video);
mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView_Video);
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
videoView_Video.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView_Video.setVideoURI(videoUri);
videoView_Video.requestFocus();
videoView_Video.start();
mediaController.show();
```

**My URI:**

```
videoUri = rtsp://v2.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQm-LZitWsUGKxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

Now I Am getting an error as below:

```
 1. http youtube = false, scheme = rtsp
 2. Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
 3. Error (1,-2147483648)
 4. Error: 1,-2147483648
```

And a dialog with a message :

[image]

Please suggest any answer to overcome this.

Comment: I faced the same issue and discovered that there was a bug in Youtube api as some videos were playing successfully and some were not . After searching a lot I was unable to find a stable solution back then.You should check if you are using the latest YouTube api as latest api always has bug fixes

Comment: here is a solution, it worked for me 
[link](stackoverflow.com/questions/12909515/play-youtube-video-in-videoview-within-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the proper API instead of manually parsing and finding videos.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

you just import the proper YouTubeVideoPlayer and things work fine.

ps.: I don't suggest using this in a ViewPager, I only had problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) that enables you to incorporate video playback functionality into your Android applications. The API itself is very easy to use and works well. For example, here is how to create a new activity to play a video using the API.

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, "<<YOUTUBE_API_KEY>>", "<<Youtube Video ID>>", 0, true, false);   
startActivity(intent);
```

See [this](http://sapandiwakar.in/streaming-youtube-videos-in-android/) for more details.